# How to address to upload_path in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I install my CI in `root/admin` and i have another folder (`root/image`) where my files uploaded here. I tested these addresses but nothing uploaded

```
 $config['upload_path'] =realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'../../image/'

 $config['upload_path'] $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'../image/'
```

Also i have image folder with 777 permision.

Any ideas?

Comment: print your upload_path in the controller where the will get uploaded

Comment: i print them and they see the address correctly but i'm unable to upload if i change the path to './uploads/' it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/csv';
```

try this way or you can use `base_url`